# AWS Lambda SQS Trigger

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have added a new AWS Lambda in visual studio. It has generated a function that passes a SQS Message.

The template I have been generated is similar to the one here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html

I can't for the life of me find anywhere that tells me where to pass the queue name? So that my lambda can trigger after a message has been put into that queue. I imagine its a property in that json file? How about a schedule? Anyone know the name of the property to add a schedule?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using CloudFormation to create the Lambda function.

To trigger that Lambda function from SQS, you should create an [AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html). For example, in YAML:

```
Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
Properties: 
  BatchSize: 1
  Enabled: true
  EventSourceArn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:444455556666:queue1
  FunctionName: myfunc
```

Increase the `BatchSize` if you want SQS messages batched.

Comment: So that version does not have the "handler" property. So how does it point to the correct handler in my code? There doesn't seem to be much documentation around this

Comment: The handler is defined as part of the Lambda function.